# python virtualenv always install global

Tags: python

In Window

First, I install virtualenv package and create virtual env

```
virtualenv 20.16.3

# 1.
c:\>virtualenv xxx
 
#2. go scripts folder and activate virtual env
c:\xxx\Scripts>activate

# 3. install package
(xxx) c:\> pip install django
```

Then I open new cmd

```
C:\> pip list

# output
Package      Version
------------ -------
asgiref      3.5.2
distlib      0.3.5
Django       4.1
filelock     3.8.0
pip          22.2.1
platformdirs 2.5.2
setuptools   63.2.0
sqlparse     0.4.2
tzdata       2022.2
```

I can see django package is in global.

Do I make some mistake?

Comment: Where is Python installed (what folder)? And did you install it to be on the path? It would appear that when running `pip` from C: root, you're somehow still not running the `pip` for the activated environment. You should try running `where pip` and `where python` before installing a package, to ensure that your setup didn't somehow mess up its pathing.

Comment: before the path, it is show (xxx). Does it mean it is in xxx virtual env? So, in that xxx env, pip install package. I seach some example in internet, it also show like that.